# How to identify multiple parameters using cssSelector in Selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone tell how to identify the following element in `selenium webdriver`. Following is the `html` version of it :

```
<select ng-model="tripDetails.destinationId" ng-change="$parent.$parent.$parent.updateTripSourceCity($index)" required="" class="ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required">
```

Comment: please update your coding  part

Comment: <select ng-model="tripDetails.destinationId" ng-change="$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.updateTripSourceCity($index)" required="" class="ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required">
                        <option value=""></option>

Comment: @SaEChowdary this is the html version of it

Comment: got it previously you  commented it in the question

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Here's a CSS selectors reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 1):

Try to identify it by class name with following `CSS` selector

```
select.ng-touched.ng-dirty.ng-valid-parse.ng-valid.ng-valid-required
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the classes on this are not unique, so it would probably be best to select by the `ng-model`. Try this as the CSS selector:

```
'select[ng-model="tripDetails.destinationId"]'
```

Comment: it didnt work throwing error that the element not found.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is better to search that particular element using xpath. First search any parent element using xpath which is above in hierarchy of the above mentioned element and then from that parent search your element. Try something like this

```
//parent-xpath/child-xpath(mentioned element)
//div[@id='element-id']/select[@ng-model='tripDetails.destinationId']
```

Comment: `CSS` selector doesn't work in this way `//parent-css/child-css`... It's looks like `XPath`. `CSS` selector should be `parent-css child-css`. Moreover, OP has said that `select[ng-model="tripDetails.destinationId"]` was not found. Obviously, `div[id='element-id'] select[ng-model='tripDetails.destinationId']` should return same result